# Adding DWORD values in Regedit without knowing the keys' location

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, automation, network-adapter

I recently added a few additions to my registry to disable Nagle's algorithm and so I want to create a reg edit file with these additions so my friends can use without having to go into it themselves.

I've made reg files in the past, but never this complex I should say. Not sure how to determine the location because it asks for their NIC interface which you must find via IP. I looked everywhere on how to accomplish this with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to your question, it comes in two parts.

1. `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces` is where you will find the list of network adapters in the registry
2. In order to know which network adapter you wish to modify, you can either look at the IP address that is listed in the registry or you can go to: Device Manager > Network Adapter > Right-click and select Properties > Details > Driver Key

Comment: But in the reg file how can I determine the user's IP so that it can automatically add the dword value in the correct NIC folder?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it impossible to do this with .reg files only.

To expand on BlueBerryDelight's question, the problem here is that some registry values need to be added to certain registry keys - but we don't know their location. We do know that they're all subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`.

We only have to modify certain ones to disable Nagle's algorithm properly. Of course, you could also find all the available subkeys and add necessary values to all of them.

To my understanding, we only need to add values to those subkeys that contain values like `IPAddress` or `DhcpIPAddress`. The values that need to be added are:

- "TcpAckFrequency"=dword:1
- "TcpDelAckTicks"=dword:0
- "TCPNoDelay"=dword:1

I used a for loop in powershell to acomplish this:

```
cd HKLM:\
$keys=Get-ChildItem -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\tcpip\parameters\interfaces"
$name=$keys | Where-object { $_.Property -like '*IPAddress*' }
foreach ($key in $name) {
new-itemproperty -path $key -name "TcpAckFrequency" -value "1" -PropertyType "DWord"
new-itemproperty -path $key -name "TcpDelAckTicks" -value "0" -PropertyType "DWord"
new-itemproperty -path $key -name "TCPNoDelay" -value "1" -PropertyType "DWord"
}
```

This will modify settings for all network adapters.